# Can't understand, why MongoDB doesn't update document, when i am using the same function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the 2 functions for my telegram bot

```
async function createData(msg) {
    try {
        await mongo.db('ProfessionWalker').collection('Users').replaceOne({_id:msg.from.id}, {"_id": msg.from.id,
            "canThrowDice": true,
            'playerPos': 0,
            'enemyPos': 0,
            'leftQuestions': false,
            'gameOver': false,
            'Developer': false}, {upsert: true})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return "Error", DisplayError(msg.chat.id,"MongoDB:", err)
    } finally {
        await mongo.close()
    }
}

async function saveData(msg, userdata) {
    try {
        await mongo.connect()
        await mongo.db('ProfessionWalker').collection('Users').replaceOne({_id:msg.from.id}, {"_id": msg.from.id,
        "canThrowDice": userdata.canThrowDice,
        'playerPos': userdata.playerPos,
        'enemyPos': userdata.enemyPos,
        'leftQuestions': userdata.leftQuestions,
        'gameOver': userdata.gameOver,
        'Developer': userdata.Developer}, {upsert: true})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return "Error", DisplayError(msg.chat.id,"MongoDB:", err)
    } finally {
        await mongo.close()
    }
}
```

I don't know, why, but createData() creates document and write the data i need. And saveData() don't update the data i need. But i am using the same functions.
P.S. Object userdata really contains all the data, that listed in the save function

I am tried to use mongodb's updateOne() and replaceOne() function with and without {upsert: true}, but still the data is creating, but not saving.

Upd: right now save function looks like this:

```
async function saveData(msg, userdata) {
    try {
        await db.findOneAndUpdate({id:msg.from.id}, {$replaceWith: {
        "canThrowDice": userdata.canThrowDice,
        'playerPos': userdata.playerPos,
        'enemyPos': userdata.enemyPos,
        'leftQuestions': userdata.leftQuestions,
        'gameOver': userdata.gameOver,
        'Developer': userdata.Developer}})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return "Error", DisplayError(msg.chat.id,"MongoDB:", err)
    }
}
```

Telegram bot still can create data, but not edit it. According to MongoDB Metrics I don't see any attempts to update the data.

Comment: You could try not to replace the id in the saveData(). I guess there is a possibility that mongodb doesnt like to replace the id if it was what was used to selected the document.

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: Just some debugging ponderings ... Presumably `mongo` is already connected when calling `createData`.  Does `saveData` work if `mongo` is already connected and `await mongo.connect()` is removed from the function?

Comment: I didn't notice it. At first I had connection and disconnection to mongodb in both functions. It didn't help. Then I removed all connections and connected to mongodb once in a separate file. That didn't help either.

Comment: Bot can create data and read it each time, but can't update the data.

Answer (score 0):

by default, `_id` is defined as `unique` || [index-unique](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) where you cant change the value.

if you want change the value of `_id`, you must remove the document and create a new one.

according to your code, you should remove `_id` from operation `update()/updateOne()/replaceOne()`:

```
{
  //_id: msg.from.id,  => remove
  canThrowDice: userdata.canThrowDice,
  playerPos: userdata.playerPos,
  enemyPos: userdata.enemyPos,
  leftQuestions: userdata.leftQuestions,
  gameOver: userdata.gameOver,
  Developer: userdata.Developer,
},
```

suggestion:

- initiate the mongo connection in outside of these functions

example: *for MongoDB only need to run in One file*

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
//initiate database name here if only connect to 1 database
const mongoUrl = `mongodb+srv://yourConnetionUri/ProfessionWalker`; 

const conOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true };

const mongoDb = new MongoClient(mongoUrl, conOptions);

async function initConnection() {
  try {
     await mongo.connect()
     console.log('Connection to DB established');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log('Connection to DB failed.');    
  }
}
initConnection()

async function createData(msg) {
  try {
    await mongoDb.
       collection("Users")
      .create( // use create/insertOne instead
        ....
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return "Error", DisplayError(msg.chat.id, "MongoDB:", err);
  } finally {
    await mongoDb.close();
  }
}

async function saveData(msg) {
  try {
    mongoDb.
       collection("Users")
      .update( // use update/updateOne instead
        ....
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return "Error", DisplayError(msg.chat.id, "MongoDB:", err);
  } finally {
    await mongo.close();
  }
}
```

example: *export MongoDB so it can be used anywhere;*

```
//initMongoConnection.js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
//initiate database name here if only connect to 1 database
const mongoUrl = `mongodb+srv://yourConnetionUri/ProfessionWalker`; 

const conOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true };

const client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl, conOptions);

async function initConnection() {
  try {
     await mongo.connect()
     console.log('Connection to DB established');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log('Connection to DB failed.');    
  }
}

module.export = { mongoDb: client, dbConnect: initConnection}
```

Comment: I need to check, is document with UserID was already created and if so - don't create another document in collection

Comment: use query `findOneAndUpdate` with option `{upsert: false}`. reff: [findOneAndUpdate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue